# ASP.NET Core 2: how to RedirectToPage with area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

`RedirectToPage("Companies")` will redirect to `/Pages/Companies.cshtml` (from an ASP.NET MVC controller)

But what if want redirect to this page `/Areas/MyArea/Pages/Companies.cshtml` ?

All those and many others don't work:

```
RedirectToPage("/MyArea/Companies.cshtml") 
RedirectToPage("MyArea/Companies.cshtml") 
RedirectToPage("./MyArea/Companies.cshtml") 
RedirectToPage("/MyArea/Companies") 
RedirectToPage("MyArea/Companies") 
RedirectToPage("./MyArea/Companies")
```

Sometimes I get "Page not found" error. Sometimes get "Specify a root relative path with a leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page". There are no `Pages` folder. I know  all this can change all rules again.

P.S. Razor pages configred with plain .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1); no specific routing added.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the [overload of RedirectToPage that takes an object representing RouteValues](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/areas#routing-and-url-generation):

```
return RedirectToPage("/Companies", new { area = "MyArea" });
```

Note that the `'/'` is required if you use `RedirectToPage` in a controller (or anywhere outside of a Razor Page). Otherwise it is not required (but will still work).

Comment: It is strange but this doesn't work either. Should I add some routing to the AddRazorPagesOptions ?

Comment: There are no Pages folder in my project folder.

Comment: Also I have standard Idenity area. RedirectToPage("Account/AccessDenied", new { area = "Identity" }); doesn't work either. With the same error: Specify a root relative path with a leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page.

Comment: Interesting. It works fine for me without the leading '/', both with and without a Pages folder. I suspect the difference is that you are working within an MVC controller whereas my tests are from within a Razor Page handler method.

Comment: Yes -the error message is clear. RedirectToPage needs the forward slash if you are using it outside of a Razor Page (e.g. in an MVC controller). I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`return RedirectToPage("/Companies", new { area = "MyArea" });`

Works under plain `.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);` no specific routing configured.

I feel this will be a popular question... Thanks to Mike Bring, he show me a path.

P.S. If you have Pages folder - all rules will be changed once more. That is the way how "Razor Pages" try to run out from "MVC magic"